# How to add additional properties to chrome tab when create it

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to pass a parameter to the tab when create it.

```
 chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL, user_id:"1234" });
```

And in the content/background script i must take user id and send it with ajax.

I couldn't figure how to do that out.

How can i pass additional properties to a tab when create it ?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do this? You have no control over the tab creation process once you initiate it. How would you retrieve the parameter you sent? There's no reason for that functionality to exist. Take a look at [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), which allows you to communicate with content script from background script and vice verse.

For example you could call `tabs.create` and provide a callback to it. Then, from the callback parameter ( which is basically and object representing the created tab), pass on the message to that specific created tab.